# Writing a private function to expand an array if capacity has run out

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a class where it starts with a small array to put values in. My objective is if the number of values exceed the capacity, the array expands to fit the remaining values. For example, if I had 5 numbers, the array would expand to accommodate the fifth value.

The object actually creates an array at run time. So when I wrote the function to expand, its actually creating a new array and pointing to it.

Heres the class

```
class DVec // self expanding array
{
private:
    //[0...n-1] are the values, [0..cap-1] exist
    int n;
    double* a;
    int cap; 
    void expand(double*);

public:
    DVec(); // constructs an empty DVec
    void add(double v); //adds v to the end of this DVec
    int size();
    double pop(); // removes and returns the last value (pre: not-empty)
    double get(int idx); // returns value at idx in this DVec
    void set(double v, int idx); // sets this DVec at idx to be v
};
```

Constructor

```
DVec::DVec()
{
    cap = 4;
    a = new double[cap];
    n = 0;
}
```

Heres the code that I'm testing it with

```
void DVec::add(double v)
{
    a[n++] = v;
    if (n == cap) { expand(a); }
}

void DVec::expand(double*)
{
    double* temp = new double[n*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = a[i];
    }
    *a = *temp;
}


int main()
{
    DVec a; DVec* p = new DVec();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        a.add(i * i);
    }

    cout << a.get(5);
}
```

My problem is that it keeps bombing out if I set the for loop to i<6. Anything lower its fine.

It comes back say it threw exception:

```
if (!has_cctor)
     cexit();
```

My questions is what is this? Is it because I made a pointer equal a pointer(a* = *temp)? Or am I not even in the same galaxy as the correct way to write the function?

Edit:

Thanks for all the help guys. I made changes and it all works now.

```
{
    double* temp = new double[cap++];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = a[i];
    }
    a = temp;
}

DVec::DVec()
{
    cap = 0;
    a = new double[cap];
    n = 0;
}

void DVec::add(double v)
{
    if (n >= cap) { expand(a); }
    a[n++] = v;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to you use the standard llbrary?

Comment: this is what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: Where is `cap` adjusted? It looks like `add` will only call `expand` when `n` is equal to 4.

Comment: Ted: I am not supposed to use the standard library.

Comment: sp2danny: Instructor specifically said use arrays

Comment: jkb: OMG! i don't know how I overlooked it. I changed it to >=.

Comment: @WenHawx: My point was that you should probably be updating `cap` to reflect the newly expanded size of your array.

Comment: @jkb: Would I have to update cap if I am pointing to a new array?

Comment: @WenHawx: Yes. Your test compares `n` to `cap`, but `cap` only ever contains 4, the size of your initial array.

Comment: @jkb: Thanks for your help. I took your advice and changed cap to update as n gets bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks like the problem:

```
*a = *temp;
```

I assume you meant to replace `a` with `temp`, but what you've written is equivalent to this:

```
a[0] = temp[0]
```

You should write this instead:

```
a = temp;
```

You also need to remember to `delete a` before overwriting it, otherwise you will have a memory leak, as well as to update `cap`, or you will have further problems.

---

I assume you are doing this as an academic exercise rather than as a solution to a real-world problem. If not, you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), as the standard library implementers have already done all the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks for you help.I took your advice and changed my code to update cap as n gets bigger.